# How do I move a file to a non-empty directory in java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to move an exe but I'm getting DirectoryNotEmptyException. Do I have to use another method or is there something I'm missing.

```
try {
    Path rbx = Path.of(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\test\\something.txt");
    Path target = Path.of(System.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA")+ "\\toIt\\4ddd");
    Files.move(rbx, target, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: `myFile.renameTo(new File("/the/new/place/newName.file"));`

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen No need to switch to `java.io.File` when `java.nio.file.*` should work just fine (and is the superior API, in my opinion). The OP just needs to either recursively delete the target directory or make the target the actual file `...\\toIt\\4ddd\\something.txt`.

Answer (score 4):

`Files.move` isn't like the shell `mv` command. The 'target' **has to include the actual file name**. In other words, if your intent is for the `something.txt` file to cease being at `~/src/test/something.txt` and start being at `$LOCALAPPDATA/toIt/4ddd/something.txt`, then you actually have to add `something.txt` to the target.

The reason you get this error is that the instruction you are running is telling the system: **DELETE** the entire `4ddd` directory and once it is completely gone, make a text file named `4ddd`. Which `Files.move` won't do, even if you use REPLACE_EXISTING.